# Setting websocket disconnect code or reason in Tornadoweb

Tags: web, websocket, tornado

I'm working on a robotics web application that connects to the server using Websocket. Server is built on RosBridge and implemented with Tornado Web.

For the web UI, use can have the websocket disconnected for the following 3 reasons.
 - Server is down.
 - Another user has kicked you out of the session.
 - Session token has expired.

The best way for the server to convey this information to the UI is to set the close reason and/or code (only need one of the two) to the UI. My understanding is that websocket protocol allows for that, but the option seems to be missing from the Tornado API.

Answer (score 0):

The "close reason" field is not currently supported in Tornado.  See https://github.com/facebook/tornado/issues/890